# Install phpmyadmin on centos 5.5 with php 5.3.3

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos

Hi every time I try to install phpmyadmin on Centos 5.5 which is running PHP 5.3.3 I get an error: php53-common conflicts with php-common.

the command i am running: # yum install phpadmin

i cannot find any package for phpmyadmin elsewhere. what is the solution? will i face similar problems with other packages for php53 ?

I have also tried to install it manually. extracting the tarball and putting it in /usr/share/phpmyadmin. Then i have created the config.inc.php file and added /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf. But to no avail. What am i missing?

Comment: Welcome to package hell. This is a common problem if you install packages from different sources. A couple of solutions: 1) Package phpmyadmin yourself. 2) Create a fake php-common package which does not conflict with php53-common and install that. 3) Install phpmyadmin without use of the package system. 4) Ask on Server Fault (if youare a professional sysadmin) or Superuser (if you are not).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but this may help some people: http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.6-php53-common-conflicts-with-php-common